# making NSArray global

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, global

i have NSarray which i want to acces from all of my methods,(i want it Global), i m going to populate this array in one of my methods defined in .m file(only once).
 my question is ... is it really possible to declare a NSArray in .h and define it place somewhere else or it just has to be defined when it is declared(initialization).

**MY CURRENT CODE**

.h file

```
@interface slots2ViewController : UIViewController {
NSArray* paylinesArr;
}
```

i m calling follwing method from ViewDidLoad

.m file

```
-(void)init_payline_arr
  {
NSString* filePath = @"/Users/net4uonline/Desktop/slots2/paylines.txt";//filepath...
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
paylinesArr = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
    }
```

i m not able to use paylinesArr array from other methods the app crashes if follwing function is getting called

```
-(IBAction)ShowVal

 {
  NSLog(@"number of elements! %@",[paylinesArr count]);
  }
```

Or
should i use NSMutabbleArray instead?

if you want to see then i have uploaded my desktop video while i m using debug tools!
[the link to video](http://rapidshare.com/files/2931782705/iShowU-Capture7.mov)

in this video i press the record button of the debugger(i have ns zombie enabled and the retain count as well),the app starts,i press spin button and apparently it crashes...then i show you the code which has

```
   paylinesArr = [[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] retain];
```

which retains the paylineArr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` won't help you! The reason of your error is that your `paylinesArr` variable is autorelease variable, so probably it was deallocated before ShowVal is called. Try to retain it like

```
-(void)init_payline_arr {
    ...
    paylinesArr = [[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] retain];
    ...
}
```

This should work. But don't forget to release it in `viewDidUnload` method:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    ...
    [paylinesArr release];
}
```

Comment: no...it doesnt work..it still crashes!
and also if i do any operations of palinesArr  from ViewDidLoad after the paylineArr initialization function returns,it works

Comment: @Yadnesh: Try to use leaks performance tool. Enable NSZombie in settings and see what happens. By the way, could you please give a crash log?

Comment: this is too supprising if i dont use retain the app crashes for the reason you thought of
but after i use retain no warning or NSzombie detects error but app still crashes at the same point

Comment: if you want to see then i have uploaded my desktop video while i m using debug tools!!!

https://rapidshare.com/files/2931782705/iShowU-Capture7.mov

Comment: @Yadnesh: I have noticed one another mistake - in NSLog(@"number of elements! %@",[paylinesArr count]); you should use %d instead of %@. %@ is used for objects only, whereas count returns NSUInteger which is just a type synonym for unsigned int.

Comment: you r rite!!!
i just dont understand after having so many sofesticated tools they didnt throw a warning
everything s working good now thanks for the help!!